# HTML5 Canvas Isometric map depth sorting

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, isometric

I'm have problem with Isometric. I'm don't know how to name this "problem", but I'm show you some sceen what I get and what I'm need to get.

My code now drawing something like: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_rqhF_8E1nlA/R59d_PmoREI/AAAAAAAAAGo/3yHpmy55moc/s400/lore2.png

But I'm need draw something like this:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_rqhF_8E1nlA/R59epfmoRFI/AAAAAAAAAGw/cE_o-A0bvm0/s400/lore3.png

I'm hear this is "Depth sort" But what it is? how I'm can apply to my code and where I'm can learn this?

My code: http://jsdo.it/keichioor/exU1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your sprites by farthest to nearest (so nearer sprites are rendered over the behind ones).

So...

```
blocks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.z - b.z;
});
```

Comment: Thanks alex, but I'm trying implement your code, but nothing change. :(

Comment: Ech, I'm now understand! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I thinking this is what your looking for, let me know

I just forked your project

http://jsdo.it/EricRobinson/8h4E

Comment: No, I'm not this need. In your example you just move block to another position, but thanks :)

Comment: I did that so that It would display the block in behind the other. like your table picture. But are you looking for a way to sort the blocks so that you get this effect?